# Exception in Thread Main : ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, hadoop, jar

I'm running hadoop in a school cluster. I get exception in thread main with class not found exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: movielens.MovieLensDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

But I'm aware that I have to use full package name in the command and i have done the same. Following is the command I used

```
hadoop jar movielens.jar movielens.MovieLensDriver input output
```

Following is the code for my driver class.

```
package movielens;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl;

public class MovieLensDriver {

    public static class JobRunner implements Runnable {
        private JobControl control;

        public JobRunner(JobControl _control) {
            this.control = _control;
        }

        public void run() {
            this.control.run();
        }
    }

    public static void handleRun(JobControl control)
            throws InterruptedException {
        JobRunner runner = new JobRunner(control);
        Thread t = new Thread(runner);
        t.start();

        while (!control.allFinished()) {
            System.out.println("Still running...");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Program started");
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err
                    .println("Usage: MovieLensDriver <input path> <output path>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        JobConf conf1 = new JobConf(movielens.MovieLensDriver.class);
        conf1.setMapperClass(MoviePairsMapper.class);
        conf1.setReducerClass(MoviePairsReducer.class);

        conf1.setJarByClass(MovieLensDriver.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf1, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf1, new Path("temp"));

        conf1.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf1.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        conf1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf1.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        JobConf conf2 = new JobConf(MovieLensDriver.class);
        conf2.setMapperClass(MoviePairsCoOccurMapper.class);
        conf2.setReducerClass(MoviePairsCoOccurReducer.class);

        conf2.setJarByClass(MovieLensDriver.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf2, new Path("temp"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf2, new Path(args[1]));

        conf2.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);

        conf2.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf2.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        conf2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        Job job1 = new Job(conf1);
        Job job2 = new Job(conf2);

        JobControl jobControl = new JobControl("jobControl");
        jobControl.addJob(job1);
        jobControl.addJob(job2);
        job2.addDependingJob(job1);
        handleRun(jobControl);

        System.out.println("Program complete.");

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

It has been a frustrating search for the bug for last 3 hours and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `MovieLensDriver` actually contained within the jar file?

Comment: Yeah I could open the jar file and see that class file.

Comment: Are you still having a problem with this?  I'm interested to see if the libjars method worked for you.

Comment: @JamCon, I could not get a chance to try if this is working as I am running out of time for assignment submission. I will try this in a day and will update here after I pass through my deadline. Thank you for taking time to respond and help in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the 'libjar' option, which will take the jar and place it in the distributed cache.  This makes the jar available to all of the job's task attempts.  Notice that the libjars argument takes a comma separated list, not a colon or semi-colon separated list.

`export LIBJARS=/path/jars1,/path/jars2,/path/movielens.jar`
`hadoop jar movielens.jar movielens.MovieLensDriver -libjars ${LIBJARS} input output`